# sequence "testsequence" is not yet defined in this session in postgresql java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbi

I am using java application with google juice as a injector along with jdbi  as database layer.I need to fetch sequence from database using java code.

I have tables in database for the application,which sequence are not used.But for other purpose I need sequence value as current ,next and last.

although the following queries are working in pg-admin

```
select currval('testsequence'); 

select nextval('testsequence'); 

select last_value FROM testsequence;
```

the code is as follows.

```
public long getCurrentSequenceFromDB()
{
    LOGGER.info("SequenceHelper :getCurrentSequenceFromDBSTART");
    try (Handle handle = jdbi.open())
    {
        SequenceDAO squenceDAO = handle.attach(SequenceDAO.class);
        long sequence = squenceDAO.getCurrentSequence();
        if (sequence != 0)
        {
            LOGGER.info("SequenceHelper :getCurrentSequenceFromDBEND");
            return sequence;
        }
        else
        {
            LOGGER.info("SequenceHelper :getCurrentSequenceFromDBsequence sequence is null");
            return 0;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Error in getting sequence from database", e);
        throw new SignageServiceException(ErrorCodes.UNEXPECTED_ERROR, "Error in getting sequence from database", e);
    }
}
```

and at query level as:

```
@SqlQuery("select currval('public.testsequence')")
public long getCurrentSequence();
```

I get error as

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: currval of sequence "testsequence" is not yet defined in this session
```

Answer (score 5):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) says

> currval
>
> Return the value most recently obtained by nextval for this sequence **in the current session**. (An error is reported if nextval has
>   never been called for this sequence in this session.) Because this is
>   returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether
>   or not other sessions have executed nextval since the current session
>   did.

So you need to call `nextval` first, within this session.

Otherwise, if you want the last value for **any** session, you can use

```
SELECT last_value FROM sequence_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

The PostgreSQL **nextval** function **must be** called before calling the **currval** function, or an error will be thrown.
The PostgreSQL **currval** function is used to access the current value of the specified sequence. 
Note that **currval** can only be used if **nextval** has been referenced in the current user session at least once.

now its working fine with sequence of database call as,

```
    @SqlQuery("select last_value from testsequence")
    public long getLastSequence();

    @SqlQuery("select nextval('testsequence')")
    public long getNextSequence();

    @SqlQuery("select currval('testsequence')")
    public long getCurrentSequence();
```